# JMeter search result is different in the local machine and remote server machine

Tags: jmeter

JMeter search result is different in the Local machine and remote server machine.

The JMeter batch file runs both environments separately.

Run one website in JMeter but the local machine and remote server load time are different.

Both machine internet speed is proper.
[image: Local machine screenshot]
[image: Remote machine screenshot]

Comment: Please let me know how are you running the tests? It is better to run in a NON-GUI mode so that optimized resource utilization will not skew the test results. Also, please remove the listeners in your test plan while running the tests. Log the results in JTL files and view the results once the test is done.

Answer (score 2):

Several factors can influence that:

1) Network path from running JMeter to your server. You should always consider that.
If, say, you're testing microservice based on Amazon Cloud (AWS), and the downstream consumers of its data are also running in the same cloud - it doesn't make a lot of sense to run JMeter at your local machine, you have to run it at AWS as well (as your consumers do) to get realistic timings.
The travel over network path there and back would add hundreds of milliseconds, moreover, it's pretty unpredictable, deviations may be huge.

2) GUI vs Non-GUI mode, the rule of thumb: GUI is for development/debug only. It takes quite a toll on the performance.

3) Available resources on the machine - you didn't mention that at all, though mind that Java Runtime Environment is kind of far from being very lean, so if the machine is not dedicated for running especially JMeter, and especially if machine is not very powerful, the results may vary.

4) Addition to resource scope: by default, the scripts running JMeter are quite restrictive in resource allocation, and if you overwhelm the instance with a lot of threads to run, the timings may get distorted.

These are general factors, if you want it more specific to your case - show how & where (means, in what type of machine) you run your tests, and where's your target in terms of network path.

Comment: Available resource on the Remote server:                                              
JAVA SDK,                                                                                                  Processor : intel(R) Xenon CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50Ghz,                
RAM: 8GB,   System type: 64 bit OS,   Browser: Google chrome,                                                                                       Can you please tell me what other things will effect the JMeter result via a testing on server

Comment: The server looks powerful enough, but, again, the main factor is the network configuration. Figure out who/what your typical customers are and where they are to the service you're targeting (in terms of network topology). Then try to put your JMeter to the same conditions (in terms of network topology) and test from there - this way you may collect kind of the "real world" timings. Or, on the contrary, place your JMeter server as close to system under test as possible - this way you'll get kind of a "pure" service performance.